# Insert avoid duplicate same table

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

I'm starting with SQL and programming as a whole.

I'm trying to insert some rows into my table, but I get an error if some row with same value already exists.

I need to add a record in the table "GPointBagCalender" a date for each LOGINUID, with SEALTYPE always equal to 4. The problem is that if I record a duplicate of LOGINUID and the date, it gives me an error of primary key.

I've tried *IF NOT EXISTS*

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT LoginUID, RegDate, SealType
                   FROM GPointBagCalender
                   WHERE RegDate = CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-07-25 01:32:00', 120))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO GPointBagCalender 
            SELECT DISTINCT
                g.LoginUID, 
                CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-07-25 01:32:00', 120), 4
            FROM 
                GPointBag g
    END
END
```

and *WHERE NOT EXISTS*

```
INSERT INTO GPointBagCalender 
    SELECT DISTINCT  
        g.LoginUID, CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-07-25 01:32:00', 120), 4
    FROM  
        GPointBag g
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT LoginUID, RegDate, SealType
                    FROM GPointBagCalender
                    WHERE RegDate = CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-07-25 01:32:00', 120))
```

In `WHERE NOT EXISTS` case, I get "0 rows affected". In the `IF NOT EXISTS` case, it only executes the command, or if there's no one register matching the date, it records a row for each LOGINUID.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: If primary keys are `LoginUID` and `SealType` only, then you need change your table to have `RegDate` as part of primary key as well.

Comment: This leaves too much open to help you... Please post the `CRATE TABLE` statements of the tables and sample data for them as `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: sorry, im using sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're using MySQL, but this should work on most DBs.

Use: `INSERT IGNORE INTO` which will silently ignore errors when encountering duplicate records.

Comment: Seems like OP uses Sql Server, where `INSERT IGNORE INTO` is not valid command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you intend with:

```
INSERT INTO GPointBagCalender ( . . . ) -- list the columns here
    SELECT DISTINCT g.LoginUID,
       CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-07-25 01:32:00', 120), 4
    FROM GPointBag g
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT LoginUID, RegDate, SealType
                      FROM GPointBagCalender gbc
                      WHERE gbc.LongUID = g.LoginUID AND
                            RegDate = CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-07-25 01:32:00', 120)
                     );
```